# Samba on FreeBSD 8 and Window 8

Tags: linux, networking, windows-8, samba, freebsd

My objective is shared files form FreeBSD8.

I have installed Samba36 using ports on FreeBSD in order to automate installations. I have edited the `/usr/local/etc/smb.conf` and `/etc/rc.conf` files with the following settings; the rest are default:

`smb.conf`:

```
[global]
  valid users = myname
  workgroup = WORKGROUP
  ...

[src]
  comment = Source
  valid users =myname
  read only = no
  path = /usr/local/src
  writable = yes
  public = yes
  broweseable = yes
```

`rc.conf`:

```
samba_enable="YES"
nmbd_enable="YES"
smbd_enable="YES"
```

I already created username "myname" with smbpasswd command.
I already username acct created in FreeBSD8 using "myname", both accounts are different password. After all error free installation and configuration.

I tried to access shared folders and files on Windows 8, on the same network subnet and workgroup, but I can't login to samba on FreeBSD8. Is there any wrong in my settings?

This is my default prompt shell:

```
root@:~#
```

Comment: Can you check whether samba is running? strictly speaking, you don't need 3 statements in rc.local, you should use either the first one, or both of the other two.

Comment: After you have installed samba, you need to _start_ it with the command `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/samba start`.

Comment: Yes sir MariusMatutiae, my samba is running smoothly and network connectivity between FreeBSD8 and Windows 8 is also too. But then, I can't login to my FreeBSD8. In my network settings, I have no activated Firewall in FreeBSD8 even in front of my FreeBSD8 and Windows 8 I have no firewall for now.

Comment: [Troubleshooting Samba](http://oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch09_01.html)